# Pods install not installing all files in AFNetworking on existing project

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, afnetworking-2

Cocoapods is not installing all the files in AFNetworking 2.6.0 on an existing project. See attached images. The other two pods, ECSlidingViewController and DateTools, installed just fine.

Any suggestions on how to resolve the missing files upon `pod install` of AFNetworking on new setups?

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'ECSlidingViewController', '~> 2.0'
pod 'DateTools'
```

Podfile.lock:

- uses AFNetworking version 2.6.0
- created using Cocoapods 0.38.2

Pod install on new setup:
These are the only AFNetworking files installed on a new system of the existing project. It's missing folders/files - NSURLSession, Reachability, Security, and Serialization.
[image: These are the only AFNetworking files installed on new system. Missing folders/files are NSURLSession, Reachability, Security, and Serialization.]

Existing project:
These are all the AFNetworking files that are installed on an existing project.
[image: These are all the AFNetworking files that were installed on an existing project.]

Using Xcode 7.2, pod version 0.38.2, OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by deleting Podfile.lock, and setting a 2.6.x versions only for AFNetworking. This caused cocoapods to install AFNetworking v2.6.3 and all necessary files were installed! Might have been a bug with v2.6.0.